# How to draw a Custom Progress Cycle with PaintCode

Tags: paintcode

I am a starter with PaintCode and Know how to draw a Progress bar, but How to draw a image like below.Thks for help
with a parameter I can control the number and the Progress

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using end or start angle parameter of oval and one variable (value: 0.0-1.0) and two expressions: angle = (360-value*360) textValue = stringFromNumber(100*value) +"%". Seet this screenshot. Your drawing method is then: - (void)drawProgressWithValue: (CGFloat)value.
It is really easy.

[Making progress arc in PaintCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz7Vt.png)

<sub>— PaintCode Support</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Nice trick is to use *Pattern Stroke* with large *Gap* (like 1000) and attach variable to *Dash* attribute. This way you can create any bezier shape and animate it’s stroke as progress bar.

See this video: [Animating Apple Watch Activity Rings](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/animating-apple-watch-activity-rings-in-paintcode) (at around 3:40)